# Germany taxes at the first year living in Germany

Tags: germany, taxes

I live in Germany since July of last year (2018), and I have never been here before and now I need to declare the taxes. One of the questions, when you are filling the form up is "Did you live abroad for extended periods of time in 2018?". Should I answer yes or no?

I'm trying to do the taxes on Tarfix app and if you answer yes they are not able to proceed, but I don't know what should I answer.

Comment: You might want to look here: https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/17540/taxes-declaration-germany-how-to/17541#17541

Answer (score 2):

You should answer "yes".  Between January and June of 2018 you lived abroad.  I don't know what the exact definition of "extended period of time" is, but six months will be included.

I think you will need to engage the services of a *Steuerberater[in]*.  The one we uses charges on the basis of our income, and saves us more in additional allowances than we pay her.  See [this](https://www.aktuell-verein.de/lohnsteuerhilfeverein/kosten/) price schedule (in German, but Google translate works fine).

Ask friends/colleagues for a recommendation - most Germans will use one.